# ERROR -> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" [IntelliJ Idea, Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, slf4j

Im using oracle jdk 19.0.2, java 19 and gradle 7.4.2. Im a complete beginner and just started using IntelliJ and Kotlin.

```
fun dayOfWeek(){
    println("What day is it today?")
}
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    dayOfWeek()
}
```

^my code

```
16:13:37: Executing 'run --scan --scan --scan --scan --scan --scan'...

> Task :wrapper

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 572ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? [yes, no] yes

Gradle Terms of Service accepted.

Publishing build scan...
https://gradle.com/s/cuhlzmsulbsuk

> Task :compileKotlinJvm UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :jsProcessResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :jsBrowserProductionExecutableDistributeResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :kotlinNpmCachesSetup
> Task :jsPackageJson UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kotlinNodeJsSetup UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kotlinRestoreYarnLock UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kotlinYarnSetup UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jsTestPackageJson UP-TO-DATE
> Task :packageJsonUmbrella UP-TO-DATE
> Task :rootPackageJson UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kotlinNpmInstall UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kotlinStoreYarnLock UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jsGenerateExternalsIntegrated SKIPPED
> Task :compileKotlinJs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jsMainClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileProductionExecutableKotlinJs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jsProductionExecutableCompileSync UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jsProductionExecutableValidateGeneratedByCompilerTypeScript
> Task :jsBrowserProductionWebpack UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jsBrowserDistribution UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jvmProcessResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources SKIPPED
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jvmMainClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jvmJar UP-TO-DATE

> Task :run
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

^output

I have been absolutely dumbfounded and its honestly frustrating me. Please help

I tried searching on google and youtube, but i did not get any result that was to be used with kotlin in IntelliJ. I am yet to get a satisfactory result. A file named pom.xml is being talked about, but i cannot find it.

Comment: SLF4J is a facade, it needs an implementation. Try adding one, like `ch.qos.logback`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File-> Project Structure->Modulcs and in the folder Dependencies, just add  the following jars: slf4j-simple-2.0.x.jar and slf4j-api-2.0.x.jar (this target should be included since it is not shipped with the logger from slf4j-api.2.0x)